# NU1101 Unable to find package Pluralsight.DDD.Deps. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

Tags: asp.net, nuget, domain-driven-design, nuget-package, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I am trying to learn a course in pluralsight https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/fundamentals-domain-driven-design/table-of-contents and I have a demo application for the course available at https://github.com/ardalis/pluralsight-ddd-fundamentals.

But, during the build one of the custom public nuget package restore fails:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Pluralsight.DDD.Deps. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org   FrontDesk.Blazor.Host   C:\Users\ArunPaul\source\repos\DDD\pluralsight-ddd-fundamentals\FrontDesk\src\FrontDesk.Blazor.Host\FrontDesk.Blazor.Host.csproj    1
```

When i checked the nuget repository, it doesn't exists, but the closest package available is
`PluralsightDdd.SharedKernel`.
I tried for building the application with the `PluralsightDdd.SharedKernel` package but it never builds.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer when I posted it to Stev Smith:
https://github.com/ardalis/pluralsight-ddd-fundamentals/issues/65
It resolved my issue